# What should I rename bailFirst and bailLast functions in this code snippet from a functional programming percpective?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, algebraic-data-types

The aim here is to try and utilize functional programming associativity.

Can `bailFirst` and `bailLast` have better names?

<strike>I think `bailFirst` kind of looks like a sum type and `bailLast` looks like a product type.</strike>

update based on @Bergi comment - They return a sum data type of true and string

`validate` takes a predicate and returns true if valid and the error message if invalid.

`bailFirst` should stop at the first invalid check

`bailLast` will run all checks and concatenate the messages into one message.

```js
const validate = (pred, msg) => x => pred(x) ? true : msg;

const bailFirst = (...fns) => x => {
  for(let fn of fns) {
    const valid = fn(x);
    if(valid !== true) return valid;
  }
  return true;
};

const bailLast = (...fns) => x => {
  const msgs = [];
  for(let fn of fns) {
    const valid = fn(x);
    if(valid !== true) msgs.push(valid);
  }
  if(msgs.length) return msgs.join("\n");
  return true;
};

const type = t => validate(x => typeof x === t, `Not a ${t}`);
const str = type('string');

const minLen = min =>
  validate(v => v.length > min, `Min length is ${min}`);

const maxLen = max =>
  validate(v => v.length < max, `Max length is ${max}`);

const between = (min, max) =>
  bailFirst(str, minLen(min), maxLen(max));

const strong = validate(x => /strong_password/.test(x), 'Weak password');

const password = bailLast(str, minLen(8), maxLen(24), strong);

const between2and4 = between(2, 4);
between2and4('foo'); // true
between2and4('foooo'); // Max length is 4
password('abc123'); // Min length is 8\nWeak password
```

Comment: "*I think bailFirst kind of looks like a sum type and bailLast looks like a product type.*" - I don't see any relation to those terms. At best, you could describe the return type of all of these functions as "a sum type of `true` and `string`".

Comment: Yes you are right, I think I should have said that they return a sort of algebraic type, though I'm struggling about proper names, what would the act of concatenating the messages signify from a functional programming percpective.

Comment: It vaguely follows the debug monad pattern where functions return not just a value, but a tuple of `(value, string)`. Wrap that in its own type with the right `bind` and `pure` and it's a debug monad.

Comment: @TariqQubti Given you have multiple strings as input and one string as an output (since you are concatenating them, not putting them in a box or so), that makes it a monoid error type.

Comment: The return type of both functions is a bit weird. Maybe you should take a step back and look into the [`Either` and `Validation` types](https://medium.com/blacklane-engineering/pure-functional-validation-64a7885d22ac).

Comment: It's really subjective imho, but your `bailFirst` probably is just a `bail` and `bailLast` a non bail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've often found that difficulty to name something is a sign my abstraction isn't quite right yet. I think the awkwardness here stems from mixing of validation, error aggregation, message formatting, and your `boolean | string` return types. I agree with [bob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5536315/bob)'s recommendation to check out [Either and Validation](https://medium.com/blacklane-engineering/pure-functional-validation-64a7885d22ac) types. If you don't want to reach for a library, you can always use those ideas to help you remodel the problem.

```js
// type Valid :: { valid :: True , messages :: [] }
// type Invalid :: { valid :: False , messages :: [String] }
// type Validation :: Valid | Invalid

// valid :: () -> Valid
const valid = () => validation( true , [] )

// invalid :: [String] -> Invalid
const invalid = messages => validation( false , messages )

// validation :: (Bool, [String]) -> Validation
const validation = ( valid = true , messages = [] ) =>
    ( { valid , messages } )

// validate :: (a -> Bool, String) -> a -> Validation
const validate = ( predicate , message ) => x =>
    predicate( x )
    ? valid()
    : invalid( [ message ] )

// joinValidations :: (Validation, Validation) -> Validation
const joinValidations = ( x , y ) =>
    validation( x.valid && y.valid
              , x.messages.concat( y.messages ) )

// validateAll :: ...(a -> Validation) -> a -> Validation
const validateAll = ( ...fs ) => x =>
    foldMap( validation
           , joinValidations
           , applyTo( x )
           , fs )

// validateSome :: ...(a -> Validation) -> a -> Validation
const validateSome = ( ...fs ) => x =>
    foldMapWhile( validation
                , joinValidations
                , applyTo( x )
                , isValid
                , fs )

// applyTo :: a -> (a -> b) -> b
const applyTo = x => f => f( x )

// isValid :: Validation -> Bool
const isValid = validation => validation.valid

// foldMap :: Monoid m => (() -> m, (m, m) -> m, a -> m, [a]) -> m
const foldMap = ( mempty , mappend , f , xs ) =>
    xs.reduce( ( y , x ) => mappend( y , f( x ) )
             , mempty() )

// foldMapWhile :: Monoid m => (() -> m, (m, m) -> m, a -> m, (m, a) -> Bool, [a]) -> m
const foldMapWhile = ( mempty , mappend , f , predicate , xs ) => {
    let y = mempty()
    for ( const x of xs ) {
        if ( !predicate( y , x ) ) return y
        y = mappend( y , f( x ) )
    }
    return y
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although appropriate naming is a bit more subjective than Stackoverflow questions usually warrant, I also appreciate the sentiment of wanting to draw the right connections.

`bailFirst` kind of reminds me of `all` in Haskell or `forall` in Scala. Rewriting your js into Haskell would look something like this:

```hs
bailFirst :: a -> [a -> Bool] -> Bool
bailFirst x = all ($x)
```

The fact that it bails early is certainly nice, but doesn't affect the output of the function. So I might call it something related to `all`.

`bailLast` however, doesn't actually bail. It seems to return either a boolean or a list of validation errors which is kind of like a stack trace? I might just skip anything fancy call that something like `validateAll`.

Comment: `bailFirst` doesn't return a boolean either, it also returns a validation error (as a string) when it finds one.

Comment: Fair clarification. I did fudge the translation to more clearly draw the connection. The type sig `a -> [a -> b] -> b` is a bit less useful in Haskell.

Comment: I guess it's more like `a -> [a -> Either String ()] -> Either String ()` (although it could be `Monoid b => a -> [Either b ()] -> Either b ()`).

Comment: well it definitely has the chance to return `True`. But otherwise it returns whatever value of "failing" function is. Which could be anything if this isn't an exhaustive list of callers.

So it might actually be something more like
`a -> [a -> Either b Bool] -> Either b Bool`

Which to be fair is more useful in Haskell, but imo begs to be refactored.

Comment: Since it never returns `false` but only `true`, I simplified that to the unit type.

Comment: I can get behind that decision.

Although now that I'm looking at this: `if(valid !== true)` it looks like we're expecting the functions to return a boolean, but they don't have to. I think translating JS to Haskell is just a flawed endeavor lol.